# Regexp to find strings enclosed by ** (double-star)

Tags: regex, cocoa, objective-c++

I'm trying to find a way to make an array of matched patterns out of a string.
I'll explain myself with an example.

From a string like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor **sit** amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nulla elementum euismod mi. Morbi eu eros eget augue vestibulum semper. 
Curabitur sapien purus, **semper** in consequat eu, gravida vitae purus.
```

I need to apply a regexp to extract the words *sit* and *semper*
and I really don't know how to manage it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think a regex such as `\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}` would take care of it, and using regular expressions in Objective-C (assuming you're on an Apple platform) you'd want to look at the NSRegularExpression [iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [Mac](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this..

```
\s*{2}([^\*]+)\s*{2}
```